# 2 HOT wires together from the same breaker source

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I was replacing all fluorescent light fixtures with pot lights and when i removed a fixture, there were 2 14/2 cables connecting with the light.

I thought one was the power coming in, and the other was the power going out to another fixture.

Turns out that when I separate them, cap them off, and turned on the breaker, both had power after I tested with a NCVT (*both are from the same breaker source*).

Now I am confused as it means that both 14/2 are for power coming in? For the time being (*I'll put in a junction box*), I finished the job by keeping the two cables connected as it was initially, but i am not sure I understand why they were both hot when i separated them.

Answer (score 2):

You could be seeing a false indication from the NCVT. It happens. Re-check with a volt meter, or try powering the light fixture from just one cable and then from just the other cable. If you find that this light, and perhaps others too, remains off when it's connected to a particular cable that's a good sign that the cable isn't truly powered.